# Response back to div after ajax request

Tags: ajax, html

I have a table with 6 columns, the first column is a check box, similarly other values generated from the database.

Last is I have a submit button, so once when clicked the checkbox values are passed to the dummy.asp/php file, here depending on each checkbox selected, the operation is performed and result back to ajax request, and I want the last column div to be changed accordingly based on the request. such as passed or failed.

Can you let me know how to change the value of the div's in the last column like that checkvalue process is done or pending or any other status.

demo :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that you use jQuery, things are very simple, as you already have a success callback function,
You can test something like this:

V3:

```
// post-submit callback 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 

  var i, regex, xarr;

  $("table div").html("NOT DONE");

  regex = new RegExp(",", "g");
  xarr = responseText.split(regex);

  for(i = 0; i < xarr.length; i++)
  {
    $("#output-" + $.trim(xarr[i])).html("DONE");
  }
}
```

This supposes that all your selected items are returned by AJAX with IDs in ***responseText*** like:
VS32,VS34,... without not selected ones.

You have spaces between VSij, let's do $.trim()...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, well the lrno(first column) is a unique column with primary key but does not only begin with VS, it may be anything, like MU, BG, VS and so on it is loaded based on sql query. My only concern is once i pass the selected values to dummy2.asp, dummy2.asp performs where the work has done or not, if done it should return done and vice versa and the last column ie. output column in the table displayed should be updated with DONE or NOT DONE instead of "AJAX response will replace this content."

Comment: Thank you once again, Perfectly working fine, but only the first value is checked, rest all selected values are ignored. I have updated the code on the demo URL : http://advancepoly.com/testdb.asp, any other suggestions ?

Comment: Perfectly fine, it works like charm. Thank you so much. I am very new to this Q/A site, do let me know how to appreciate your work and close the topic ?

Comment: You selected this answer, this is the best appreiciation. You would gain the possibility to upvote answers one day soon.

Comment: ok fine thank you once again, just another thing - with respect to above query, there is some delay in process the script dummy3.asp, is there any way I can inform user that the process is going on or so using a div or any other method till the post back. ?

Comment: Put a spinning ajax-loading.gif like image before the return of ajax call, ie, set it directly by javascript on the current page, the image will be immediatement visible.

Comment: Do a search on Google, you would have choices. Or ask a well formed question with trials or failing, in order not to be sanctionned. We'll not to be permitted to discute longer without warnings.

Comment: I was able to get it done, thanks a lot for all your support.